# PyQt5 Windows 10 scaling issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 app on few different PC - I noticed that when in Windows:

"Desktop" -> "Display settings" -> "Scale and layout" -> "Change the size of text, apps and other items"

Scale is increased from 100% - app is increasing fonts but size of buttons and generally app size stays same.

That causes few issue, menu bar buttons starts to be hidden and in different buttons text isn't fully displayed, additionally buttons starts to overlay itself.

Is there possibility to automate scaling whole app when Windows scale is changed or to fully disable that option (when Windows changes scale app remains same)?

Examples:
[image]

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, \
    QApplication, QStyledItemDelegate, QAction, QMenuBar
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class AllClass(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AllClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Calibri", 9, QtGui.QFont.Normal, italic=False))

        self.tmp_label = QLabel(text='tmp')
        self.tmp_label.setMinimumHeight(20)

        self.tmp_combo = QComboBox()
        self.tmp_combo.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.tmp_combo.setMinimumWidth(130)
        self.tmp_combo.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Calibri", 8))
        self.tmp_combo.setStyleSheet("QAbstractItemView::item{margin: 2px;}")
        self.tmp_combo.setItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate())

        self.tmp_button = QPushButton()
        self.tmp_button.setText('tmp button')
        self.tmp_button.setMinimumWidth(80)
        self.tmp_button.setMinimumHeight(19)

        self.tmp_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.tmp_layout.addWidget(self.tmp_label, 1, 1)
        self.tmp_layout.addWidget(self.tmp_combo, 2, 1)
        self.tmp_layout.addWidget(self.tmp_button, 3, 1)

        self.tmp_layout.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        self.tmp_layout.setHorizontalSpacing(2)

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addLayout(self.tmp_layout, 1, 1)

        self.grid.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.grid.setSpacing(0)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addLayout(self.grid)

        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)


class TmpApp(QWidget):
    short_button = None
    s_window = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TmpApp, self).__init__(parent)

        self.menu = self.menu_bar()
        self.Rwup = AllClass()
        self.setWindowTitle('tmp app')
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.menu, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.Rwup, 2, 1)
        grid.setSpacing(0)
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        grid.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setMinimumSize(200, 100)

    def menu_bar(self):
        self.menu = QMenuBar()

        self.short_button = QAction('SHORTCUTS')
        self.menu.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Calibri", 8))
        self.menu.addAction(self.short_button)

        self.menu.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.short_button.triggered.connect(self.short_window)

        return self.menu

    def short_window(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TmpApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

As I've written that down I figured that probably issue is connected with using Fixed Size, but using Minimum Size instead can create different size of buttons than I expect.

Comment: Are you using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)?

Comment: musicamante - Yes I am

Comment: That doesn't seem like. Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your ui?